# Cannot instantiate a method

Tags: python-3.x, object, attributes

Edit: I was asked to provide the entire code, not just the relevant code.

I've read through multiple similar error questions with no similarities to this. I'm trying to create an instance to call player_build on, but I get the error "'TotalPlayers' object has no attribute 'player_build'". All I want to do is have the program show all four players: Player 1, Player 2, Player 3, Player 4. I'm using Atom and Python 3.6.2.

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def show(self):
        if self.value is 11:
            print('Jack of {}'.format(self.suit))
        elif self.value is 12:
            print('Queen of {}'.format(self.suit))
        elif self.value is 13:
            print('King of {}'.format(self.suit))
        elif self.value is 14:
            print('Ace of {}'.format(self.suit))
        elif self.suit not in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            print('Joker')
        else:
            print('{} of {}'.format(self.value, self.suit))

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.card = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ["Joker"]:
            for v in range(1, 3):
                self.card.append(Card(v, s))
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(2, 15):
                self.card.append(Card(v, s))

    def show(self):
        for c in self.card:
            c.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.card) -1, 0, -1):
            random.shuffle(self.card)

    def draw(self):
        return self.card.pop()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, player, number):
        self.player = player
        self.number = number

    def show(self):
        print('{} {}'.format(self.player, self.number))

class TotalPlayers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.starting_players = []
        self.player_build()

    def player_build(self):
        for p in ["Player"]:
            for n in range(1, 5):
                self.starting_players.append(Player(p, n))

    def show(self):
        for s in self.starting_players:
            s.show()
```

I try to run the code thusly:

```
m = TotalPlayers()
m.show()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jmcco\Desktop\Gambit Card Game\Gambit_Main.py", line 72, 
in <module>
m = TotalPlayers()
File "C:\Users\jmcco\Desktop\Gambit Card Game\Gambit_Main.py", line 57, in 
__init__
self.player_build()
AttributeError: 'TotalPlayers' object has no attribute 'player_build'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The example code works as expected, so perhaps the error occurs in a part that you've omitted.

Comment: Although it's good to hear that you're not having problems because I swear to God this code looks clean to me and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I added the error above. It's the 'object has not attribute' problem.

Comment: Is that the complete code? I don't see a reason why this error occurs. How do you run the program?

Comment: I just edited the question to include the entire code now. I'm using Python 3.6.2 and the Atom text editor.

Comment: Still works correctly for me. Try to run the program in the command-line/terminal or another editor or IDE (like IDLE which comes with Python) to see if Atom causes the error.